# JW Player: cross-browser "display:none" player behavior

Tags: css, embed, jquery-ui-tabs, jwplayer

Is there a simple, upfront method to have FF and IE treat hidden JW Players the same?

I am placing different instances of the player dynamically in jQuery generated tabs. In effect, switching tabs hides the parent div of each player. In FireFox, the tab switch and accompanying "display" change stops the player. This doesn't happen in IE. I would like it to.

What is the easiest way to have both browsers act the same? I am hoping for a CSS/HTML solution, either thorough the way the players are embedded or a style rule Otherwise I suppose I will need to add an item listener that compares the currently selected tab id to currently active players... but I'd rather not go that route.

Thanks for your tips!

**EDIT**: So, I'd rather be able to change the player CSS or markup on tab change than send stop events to all the players but the player in the currently active tab.

Comment: I had an idea involving `RemoveChild` and `AppendChild` but no dice: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=139866 maybe something there helps, the guy was in the same situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Internet Explorer. While FF, Chrome, and Safari will kill Flash, IE doesn't. The only way we've been able to ensure that the player stops is to keep track of all active players on the page and call stop.

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video

Comment: found this: "The only method to set a Flash object hidden and visible again while keeping the object running turns out to be setting a CSS class with visibility:hidden" https://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/chrome-firefox-reset-flash-plugin-if-display-property-changes-update/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript to change tabs, why are you hoping for a pure CSS/HTML solution for your problem?

I think you have to use JavaScript.

Take a look at the JW Player API:
http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Api

You can call the stop() method on the player.

```
player.stop();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm already controlling the player almost entirely through the API. The issue is that there is more than one player, which complicates things.  For FF at least, "display:none" on an ancestor div stops the player if it is playing, and makes that player not hear sent events. I was hoping IE had a style rule that effected the player in the same way. Else I have to track all the players and add a send a stop event to all of them except for the one displayed in "this" tab, which is more involved. I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my friend. I've a big trouble that doesn't make me sleep...
I've a site with:
- a div with a video (jwplayer)
- a div with a gallery (lightbox, on click popover of image)

If video play and a user (only with IE) click on a image, the popover appears over video, the video continues to play (ok!) but video goes blank!
When I close image popover, video timeline play normally but video is still blank (all black).

I've been try to use what you wrote here but without success.
This is the script I must use to insert jwplayer.

```
<div id="Player">player should load here</div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.linkfromdisplay = "true";
    flashvars.autostart = "false";
    flashvars.height = "' . $h . '";
    flashvars.controlbar = "over";
    flashvars.width = "' . $w . '";
    flashvars.repeat = "false";
    flashvars.bufferlength = "5";
    flashvars.displayheight = "' . $h . '";
    flashvars.displaywidth = "' . $w . '";
    flashvars.file = "http://blablabla.com";
    flashvars.type = "vdox";
    flashvars.provider = "vdox";
    var params = {};
    params.menu = "true";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    params.wmode = "transparent";
    params.windowless="true";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "Player";
    attributes.name = "Player";
    swfobject.embedSWF("' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/embed/mediaplayer.swf", "Player", "' . $w . '", "' . $h . '", "8","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

I tried also to stop via js video before open popover (player1.sendEvent('STOP');): video stops, but if I click on play button, remains black.

I tried also to remove video element via jquery, saving it in a variable. Then I insert a button "restore video": in Chrome works, in IE reappear video object, it play but all black.
Thanks

Comment: You should ask a new question.