# Why does JwPlayer go blank after overlay?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jwplayer

Like you may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731876/jw-player-cross-browser-displaynone-player-behavior), if I put jwplayer on my site, then a DIV in overlay appears over the player (still started) the player continues to play, but appears completely black. Audio still continues to work, but the video goes black. Naturally this issue is only in IE!

I tried with 'transparent mode' but it the results were the same.

Could someone help me with this issue please?